# Substring with special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, razor, substring

Let's say I have a string:

```
string str = "09012013 Receipt 09012013 #12"
```

I want to do substring to return "Receipt 09012013 #12", I used substring:

```
var result = str.Substring(9);
```

and the result was only "Receipt 09012013"

I tried with other special characters (%,§,$ ...), it worked, substring returned "Receipt 09012013 %12", but with # and &, substring only returned "Receipt 09012013".

Any thoughts? Thanks.

**EDIT**

My code:

```
new NaviListItem("renameBtn", "showwaitingscreen", "akte/renameakte?entityid=" + Request["parentid"] + "&aktenkurzbezeichnung=" + Model.Node.Header.Substring(Model.Node.Ordnungsnummer.Length+1), "umbenennen.png", Model.RenameVisible, "Umbenennen", "Umbenennen"),
```

Comment: For me result is "Receipt 09012013 #12". Have you wriiten your own extension method `Substring`?

Comment: It retursn ok on my computer for every special character in your question.

Comment: How do you know your result is "Receipt 09012013"? Try `MessageBox.Show(result)`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I used standard Substring. I used this in View.cshtml, to pass the value to JQueryAjaxDialog

Comment: Then you must follow @dasblinkenlight recommendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `Substring` does not depend on the characters at the end:

```
string str = "09012013 Receipt 09012013 #12".Substring(9);
```

produces `"Receipt 09012013 #12"` as its result.

Most likely this is a display issue: if you are delivering the result of the `Substring` over some sort of HTML-enabled display mechanism, the `&` and `#` would often be treated as meta-characters, and therefore require escaping.

Comment: Yes, I used it in a View.cshtml, to pass value to JQueryAjaxDialog, so, do you have solution ?

Comment: @QuiTran **"and therefore require escaping."**

Comment: @QuiTran Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` on the result of `Substring` to escape meta-characters.